# How can I change the default application locale from EN to some other language?

Tags: android

The default language of my Android application is Czech; it is the only language the application contains in its `res/values` folder. The application itself is country specific and has no sense for those who are not able to read Czech.

I have just tried to place my app on the Android Market and it sets its default language to English. It is not possible to change it neither in the market nor in the application's manifest.
I tried placing application strings into the `res/values-cs` folder, but after then the Market prevents me to upload the .apk and shows me following error:

**ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value**

After some Googling I found the `res/values` folder is mandatory, but how can I tell Market it contains Czech, not English?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get all the text data from Resources.

Thn Add this for Locale Change:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Configuration newConfig = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
newConfig.locale = Locale.ANY_OTHER_LANGUAGE;
```

Also you have to insert the string values for the other language you intend to change.

For example if you want japenes locale: Make a folder named as value-ja in res and paste all japenes text values in string.xml and make refernce to them.

**Edit**
You also need to restart the activity for settings to take effect. Code to restart activity is somewhat like below:

```
public void reload() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but we are not on the same page. I know how to localize apps. I just want Android Market (Google Play) web application force to not setting English as the default language of my application - it is simply not true.